# Why NHibernate not reflecting in-memory state when updates made with stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have a process whereby I have an NHibernate session which I use to run a query against the database. I then iterate through the collection of results, and for each iteration, using the same NHibernate session, I call a SQL Stored Procedure (using `CreateSQLQuery()` & `ExecuteUpdate()`), which ends up performing an update on a field for that entity.

When it has finished iterating over the list (and calling the SP x times), if I check the database directly in SSMS, I can see that the UPDATE for each row has been applied.

However, in my code, if I then immediately run the same initial query again, to retrieve that list of entities, it does not reflect the updates that the SP made for each row - the value is still NULL.

I haven't got any cache behavior specified against the configuration of NHibernate in my application, and have experimented with different `SetCacheMode()` when calling the query, but nothing seems to make any difference - the values that I can see directly in the DB have been updated, are not being brought back as updated when I re-query (using `Session.QueryOver()`) the database (using that same session).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `CreateSQLQuery` (to update database, single row or multiple rows does not matter), actually you are doing [DML-style operation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct) which does not update the in-memory state.
Any call to `CreateSQLQuery` or `CreateQuery` will not use/reflect tracking. These are considered out-of-the-scope of Unit Of Work.
These operations directly affect the underlying database neglecting any in-memory state.

> **14.3. DML-style operations**
>   As already discussed, automatic and transparent object/relational mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies that the object state is available in memory, **hence manipulating (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect in-memory state**. However, NHibernate provides methods for bulk SQL-style DML statement execution which are performed through the Hibernate Query Language (HQL). A Linq implementation is available too.

They (may) work on bulk data. They are necessary in some scenarios for performance reasons. With these, tracking does not work; so yes, in-memory state become invalid. You have to use them carefully.

> if I then immediately run the same initial query again, to retrieve that list of entities, it does not reflect the updates that the SP made for each row - the value is still NULL.

This is due to first (session) level cache. This is always enabled by default and cannot be disabled with `ISession`.

When you **first** load the objects, its a database hit. You get the objects *from database* - loop through them - execute commands those are out of Unit Of Work (as explained above) - and **again** execute same query **twice** to load same objects under same `ISession` instance. Second call **does not hit the database** at all.

It just return the instances from memory. As your in-memory instances are not updated at all, you always get original instances.

To get the updated instances, close the first session and reload the instances with new session.

For more details, please refer to: [How does Hibernate Query Cache work](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/)